# What are these orange spots on my fiddle fig plant?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health

I've just noticed some orange-like spots on one of the new leaves on my fiddle fig plant. I water it once a week or whenever the dirt is dry. It sits in my window from morning to evening time. Is this a sign of something wrong? What's going on?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took care of a few [Ficus Lyrata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_lyrata) when I was an interior landscaper.  Keep in mind this is another "house plant" that can grow to the size of a house (50'+ tall). They have a better appearance if they are grown as a multi stem plant.

- indoors [mealy bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug), scale or [thrip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrips) are the most common problems.
- control of those pests usually involves more than soap and water.  [Neem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica#Pest_and_disease_control) or even systemics if there is thrip
- bright diffuse indoor light
- provide less water in the fall and winter months
- spots on the leaves are common and seem to be a fungus/virus/bacteria
- changing watering habits and providing more light allow the plant to outgrow this problem so fungicides or re potting are not required
- indoor plants rarely fruit
- if you prune this plant watch for the white sticky sap from any cuts

Answer (score 2):

It looks like spider mite feeding sites - check the plant closely and thoroughly for evidence of webbing anywhere, use neem oil spray to treat it with. Spider mites like hot and dry conditions - if your plant is above a radiator or heat source, you need to find somewhere else for it. Otherwise, water when the surface of the soil feels just about dry to the touch, water thoroughly and tip away any excess water in an outer pot or tray after 30 minutes.

Comment: I disagree, more likely to be fungal spots. Ficus lyrata have a hard leaf, not common for mites